# WinForms create transparent clearable pictureBox overlays

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox, transparent

I want to create 2 transparent overlays for pictureBox in WinFrom application so I can separately draw on both and I can also clear it when I want to blank transparent overlay.

On one overlay I draw rectangles. I want these rectangles there all time.

On second overlay I draw circles but I just want to draw 1 circle and after user input clear this circle and draw another.

For now I'm using

```
var transparentOverlay = pictureBox.createGraphics();
```

But I don't know how to clear an overlay to blank transparent graphics.
I tried

1. `transparentOverlay.Clear(Color.Transparent)` which turned all overlay to black
2. `pictureBox.Invalidate()` which cleared all graphics from both overlays so my rectangles remain where they were
3. use some backup graphics which I created before any drawing and clear my overlay by assigning this graphics to it `transparentOverlay = transparentOverlayBackup` but this did nothing, all rectangles and all circles remain at their places

Is there a way to create clearable transparent graphics sticked to pictureBox?

**EDIT:**

I have a picture with text in that picture box. And what I want to do is to draw rectangles around words of the text and this rectangles should remain all the time over the picture.

Than I want to draw a single circle and wait for user to click on a screen. This is all ok but when user click on a screen, I want to clear that circle and draw another.

[image: first step show one circle]
[image: second step after user click another circle show up but firs should disappear]

```
//this method I call by click on a button to start annotation
private void ExpertAnnotate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    if (!annotationIsRunning) //check if annotation is in process or not
    {
        annotationIsRunning = true;

        annotationOverlay = pictureBox.CreateGraphics(); //create transparent overlay for drawing

        //draw rectangles around all words in text (AOIs)
        annotationAOIs.ForEach(a =>
        {
            annotationOverlay.DrawRectangle(pen, a.Start.X, a.Start.Y, (a.End.X - a.Start.X), (a.End.Y - a.Start.Y));
        });

        //subscribe mouseMove and mouseClick events on pictureBox
        pictureBox.MouseMove += HighlightAOI;
        pictureBox.MouseClick += SelectAOI;
    }

    //define brushes for drawing circles (fixations)
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.BlueViolet));
    var dotBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkBlue);
    pen.Color = Color.Blue;
    long sizeOfFixation;
    var f = Fixations[fixationCounter - 1]; //get current fixation to draw

    sizeOfFixation = (int)f.Length / FIX_SIZE_COEFICIENT; //compute size of circle
    annotationOverlay.FillEllipse(dotBrush, f.PosX - 1, f.PosY - 1, 3, 3);
    //draw fixation on overlay
    annotationOverlay.FillEllipse(brush, (f.PosX - sizeOfFixation), (f.PosY - sizeOfFixation), sizeOfFixation * 2, sizeOfFixation * 2);
}

//eventHandler for mouseMove - this method color rectangle over which mouse hover to red border
private void HighlightAOI(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this just draw last highlighted rect to black when we not yet hover mouse above it
    if (lastHighlightedAOI != null)
    {
        annotationOverlay.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), lastHighlightedAOI.Start.X, lastHighlightedAOI.Start.Y, (lastHighlightedAOI.End.X - lastHighlightedAOI.Start.X), (lastHighlightedAOI.End.Y - lastHighlightedAOI.Start.Y));
    }
    //get position of mouse sursor
    var x = pictureBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X;
    var y = pictureBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y;
    var tempFix = new Fixation() { PosX = x, PosY = y };

    //get rectangle over which mouse hover
    lastHighlightedAOI = tempFix.LiesIn(annotationAOIs).FirstOrDefault();

    if (lastHighlightedAOI != null)
    {
        //highlight rectangle by painting red border
        annotationOverlay.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), lastHighlightedAOI.Start.X, lastHighlightedAOI.Start.Y, (lastHighlightedAOI.End.X - lastHighlightedAOI.Start.X), (lastHighlightedAOI.End.Y - lastHighlightedAOI.Start.Y));
    }
}

//eventHandler for mouse click
private void SelectAOI(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get position of cursor
    var x = MousePosition.X;
    var y = MousePosition.Y;
    var tempFix = new Fixation() { PosX = x, PosY = y };

    //get rectangle which we selected by a mouse click
    var aoi = tempFix.LiesIn(annotationAOIs).FirstOrDefault();

    //assign last shown fixation to selected rectangle
    if (aoi != null)
    {
        aoi.AssignedFixations.Add(Fixations[fixationCounter - 1]);
    }

    //if it wasn't last fixation again call ExpertAnnotation function to draw another Fixation over image (!!! here I need to clear last drawn fixation (circle) disappear and draw next fixation in ExpertAnnotate method)
    if (fixationCounter != Fixations.Count)
    {
        ExpertAnnotate(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        TerminateExpertAnnotation("regular");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Clear` just means to fill everything with a color. Using a fully transparent ink (or brush or pen) will not change anything.

Comment: Additional info: the `Graphics` of the screen or a control can never has transparent areas. What do you expect when after rendering the whole screen a transparent area remains somewhere? A hole in the monitor? Instead, 'nothing' starts with black background on which you can paint 'something'. A `Bitmap` background can be transparent, though.

Comment: I forgot to say that in Picturebox I have a picture (screenshot with text). And, what I want is to set transparent area over this picture, so I can draw on it. I have such transparent area but problem is that I want something to be drawn over permanently (those rectangles) and something I want to be just temporary (those circles). So I thought I will create 2 transparent areas one over another but it behaves like it is one area. I want One area to be cleared and another remain same.

Comment: Use an image for those text and rectangles and set it as image of your picture box. Then draw the circle in paint event of picture box. When the user clicks on a new point, just invalidate the picture box and draw the circle in new point.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Please can you tell mi how? I'm totally frustrated by this stuff. Am also disappointed that such primitive thing I need to do is barely impossible to achieve. When I call `Invalidate()` and than draw something into graphics it just blinks and immediately disappear. I thought it will be easy like working with multiple layers for example in PS or Corel but it isn't. I Add my code to the question, please help.

Comment: You should put paint logic in `Paint` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) who guided me in chat to solution.

For me acceptable solution was in building multilayer image and assigning it to pictureBox.Image attribute.

I built image by loading image from file:

```
Image im = new Bitmap(path); // loads image from file
```

Then create graphics from this image:

```
var g = Graphics.FromImage(im); // creates graphics from loaded image
```

Draw all needed rectangles to this image and backup this image to some global `Image` instance:

```
var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
// draws all rectangles on the image
annotationAOIs.ForEach(a =>
{
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, a.Start.X, a.Start.Y, (a.End.X - a.Start.X), (a.End.Y - a.Start.Y));
});
g.Dispose(); // disposes used graphics
ImageBackup = new Bitmap(im); // backup image with rectangles
```

In above part I created a static part of an image, which will not change and I backed it up so next time I will just create new `Image` instance from backup without any rectangle drawing.

Then when I want to show up new circle over this image I just:

```
var image = new Bitmap(ImageBackup); // creates new instance of image with rectangles from backup
var g = Graphics.FromImage(image); // creates graphics from image

// in this part draw circle at specific point
var f = Fixations[fixationIndex];
sizeOfFixation = (int)f.Length / FIX_SIZE_COEFICIENT;
g.FillEllipse(dotBrush, f.PosX - 1, f.PosY - 1, 3, 3);
g.FillEllipse(brush, (f.PosX - sizeOfFixation), (f.PosY - sizeOfFixation), sizeOfFixation * 2, sizeOfFixation * 2);

pictureBox.Image.Dispose(); // dispose old pictureBox image
pictureBox.Image = image; // set new image

imageOverlay = pictureBox.CreateGraphics(); // get transparent graphics overlay for pictureBox so we can draw anything else over picture (in my case highlighting rectangles over which I hover a mouse)
g.Dispose(); // dispose used graphics
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best approach would be to use the OnPaint event handler for the PictureBox control and place all your drawing calls in there.

You can use the Graphics object passed to the event handler to get the surface you want to draw on (i.e. the Picture box) and then use the various methods to draw the shapes that you are after.

To draw a 'transparent' shape simply draw an outline rather than a filled shape.